# Ms Fakes Framework, NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, mocking, microsoft-fakes

Why does this code throw ShimNotSupportedException in operator?

```
ShimStreamReader.AllInstances.EndOfStreamGet = ((s)=>calls < 1);

[TestMethod]
        public void GetAllLinesFromFile__()
        { 
            int calls = 0;

            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                ShimStreamReader.AllInstances.EndOfStreamGet = ((s)=>calls < 1);
                ShimStreamReader.AllInstances.ReadLine = (s) =>
                                                             {
                                                                 calls++;
                                                                 return ";;;;;;;;;;";
                                                             };
                var streamFake = new ShimStreamReader();
                var obj = new MyFile(streamFake, ';');

                Assert.IsTrue(obj.GetAllLinesFromFile().Count() == 1);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you are running the test from Resharper or some other testrunner?

I've written a few blogposts related to this which may be helpful:

http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/visual-studio-2012-fakes-shimnotsupportedexception-when-debugging-tests/

http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/unit-testing-visual-studio-2012-fakes-in-team-city/

Comment: Yes, this exception is typical when you try running Fakes tests in a third-party test harness.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and works fine in VS 2012 RC. I did face the similar issue when I opened a solution in VS 11 Beta which was created in VS 2010. The only workaround I figured out was to create a new solution in VS 11 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible causes is missing of the fakesconfig files which should have been generated along with your xxx.fakes.dll.

I used a central project to generate Fake assemblies, and use other projects which depend on the central project to consume the generated Fake assemblies.

Let's call the Fake assembly consuming project FOO.

I did encounter the ShimNotSupportedException. After some investigation(several days!), I found that the fakesconfig files were not copied along with the Fake assemblies to the folder where FOO.dll resides. After copying fakesconfig files there, my tests passed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another case where this happens is when you have Typemock installed and it is enabled.

Disable on Typemock -> Suspend Mocking